# Ember CLI Live Reload Not Working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, livereload

I've seen other similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439380/live-reload-not-working-with-ember-cli) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285074/ember-cli-live-reload-not-working) but neither of those worked for me.

I'm on a mac and simply installed ember cli using npm and I thought it would work out of the box. Here is the server output:

```
version: 0.1.4
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events
Livereload server on port 35729
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:4200/

Build successful - 2456ms.

Slowest Trees                  | Total          
-------------------------------+----------------
EsnextFilter                   | 877ms          
TreeMerger                     | 380ms          
Concat                         | 375ms          
JSHint - Tests                 | 178ms          
EsnextFilter                   | 146ms          
ES6Concatenator                | 135ms
```

Comment: are you on mac or linux? I got it worked for mac though.

Comment: I'm on a mac - I'll update the question with that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I wasn't the only one with this issue and my friend found a solution that works.

Add the following lines to your .ember-cli in the root of your project:

```
"liveReload": true,
"watcher": "polling"
```

Once you restart the server, it should watch for changes to your directory.

Comment: Prior to ember-cli v0.2.5, this would appear to have been the default.  Since v0.2.5, I've had to set it manually.

Comment: I faced exactly similar issue for ember-cli 1.13.8. Just adding `"watcher": "polling"` also works.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Mac then install `watchman` using `brew install watchman` instead of `npm install watchman`.

And if you are using **Sublime Text** then add below code to your sublime user settings json

**Prefences -> Settings - User**

```
{
"folder_exclude_patterns":
    [
        ".svn",
        ".git",
        ".hg",
        "CVS",
        "tmp/class-*",
        "tmp/es_*",
        "tmp/jshinter*",
        "tmp/replace_*",
        "tmp/static_compiler*",
        "tmp/template_compiler*",
        "tmp/tree_merger*",
        "tmp/coffee_script*",
        "tmp/concat-tmp*",
        "tmp/export_tree*",
        "tmp/sass_compiler*",
        "tmp/javascript",
        "tmp/result",
        "tmp/transpiled"
    ]
}
```

Exit Sublime once and open again. Right now Sublime has a bug which causes conflict with watchman, so above trick might work. 
Good luck.

Comment: It still does not work. I made changes to both the application.js and application.hbs to see if it would catch either, but it didn't.

Comment: No errors - it simply doesn't respond to any saved changes. When i startup the server, it does see Watchman now.

Answer (score 1):

*Might be simplistic answer, but this was solution I needed*
In Windows, run Node cmd in **Administrator mode**

Answer (score 1):

Check **package.json** for the below devDependencies ,if not add it.

```
"ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.1"
"ember-cli-styles-reloader": "0.1.8"
```

and in **.ember-cli** file add the below configuration,

```
"liveReload": true,
"host": "0.0.0.0"
```

(For me it works only after adding host entry).